# Reading indexes from a text file

Tags: c, file

Currently, I have some code that will read each line from a text file and print it in the console. (E.G Bread 2.10, Milk 3.30)

How would I modify this only read the second index of each line(Bolded for clarity) (E.G 2.10, 3.30 and 5.50) I'd then like to multiply those numbers by 0.1 and overwrite the same file.

File Format

Bread **2.10**

Milk **3.30**

Fish **5.50**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int c;
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("oText.txt", "r");
    if (file) {
        while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF){
            putchar(c);
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: so you would like to read a char every n char inside the file?

Comment: The text file would be like a shopping list (Bread 20.0 \n Milk 30.0). I wanna isolate the price portion.

Comment: Do you mean "How can I print every other line from a file?"

Comment: @user3121023 I've edited it. I can't be more clear on what it is I'm trying to accomplish, the correct terminology is used and I've provided examples.

Comment: @Zane [code](https://onlinegdb.com/ryZLfr5iH)

Answer (score 0):

In its very simplest form, you want to read each line into a character array (a buffer) and then locate the last space in the buffer, and output from the next character to the end of the line. That will output the 2nd field in your case.

Rather than using *character-oriented* input functions like `getchar()` or `fgetc()`, *line-oriented* input functions like `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()` read an entire line at a time into a sufficiently sized buffer. (rule: don't skimp on buffer size!!) The *line-oriented* input function also read and include the `'\n'` at the end of each line in the buffer they fill. Generally you will want to trim the trailing `'\n'` from any string you are storing -- but you can also use it to your advantage to provide the `'\n'` if all you are doing is outputting the values as soon as they are read.

To find the last `' '` (space) in your buffer, the `strrchr` (string char reverse) function (provided in `string.h`) will return a pointer to the last character you specify (or `NULL` if that character is not found in the buffer) This makes your job very easy. Just read each line into a buffer, then call `strrchr (buf, ' ')` to obtain a pointer to the last space in your buffer, then simply print from the next character to the end of line.

Reading from `stdin` (which you can simply redirect your file on `stdin`), your code reduces to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1024   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (void) {

    char buf[MAXC];     /* buffer (array of char) to hold line */

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {          /* read each line */
        char *lastspace = strrchr (buf, ' ');   /* locate last space */
        if (lastspace != NULL)                  /* if space located */
            fputs (++lastspace, stdout);        /* output from next char on */
    }
}
```

(**note:** how `fputs` is used to output the line relying on the `'\n'` that was read and included in `buf` by `fgets`)

**Example Input File**

Not knowing whether you had blank lines in your input file as shown, they were left in place (and **note:** they are gracefully skipped as `strrchr` will return `NULL` when the only thing in `buf` is the `'\n'`)

```
$ cat dat/breadmilk.txt
Bread 2.10

Milk 3.30

Fish 5.50
```

**Example Use/Output**

Running the code above with the file contents passed in on `stdin` results in the following:

```
$ ./bin/breadmilkcost < dat/breadmilk.txt
2.10
3.30
5.50
```

**A Flexible Approach**

Also note that because your are locating the last space in the file instead of just trying to read the second word, etc.., this method would work equally well and have the same output even if your file contained:

```
Bread (two loaves) - 2.10

Milk (one carton) - 3.30

Fish (Alaskan Sockeye) - 5.50
```

Look things over and look up the man pages for [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3p.html) and [`strrchr()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html) to make sure you understand how things are working. If you have continuing questions, just drop a comment below and I'm happy to help further.